# Converting a Generic variable to a specific Class type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Here is my Code

```
  public class MaterialRepository<T> where T : Material, new()
    {
        public List<T> ListMaterial { get; set; }

        public MaterialRepository(List<T> listMaterial)
        {
            ListMaterial = new List<T>();
            ListMaterial = listMaterial;
        }

   public T SearchMaterial(T inputMaterial)
    {
        T resultMaterial = new T();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(BendingMaterial))
        {
           //do something here        
        }

        return resultMaterial;

    }
```

My question is how can i convert resultMaterial to a specific derived class(BendingMaterial) of Material? 
and also in the *//do something here..* part, how can i find a BendingMaterial in the ListMaterials using BendingMaterial specific properties if ListMaterials is generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have classes like these with other properties, methods, and what have you:

```
public class Material
{
    public decimal Density { get; set; }
}

public class BendingMaterial : Material
{
    public string Bendability { get; set; }
}

public class OtherMaterial : Material
{
    public bool IsOther { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your methods, you can write code like this to get the child types of the individual list items in the List of Material objects and access their specific properties and methods like so.  This should work for a list T even if you aren't using the where T: Material constraint because even if you're throwing a Checkbox or object into a purely generic list, the "if (m is BendingMaterial" will match the expected Material object and handle it accordingly.

```
List<T> ListMaterial = new List<Material>();
ListMaterial .Add(new BendingMaterial());
ListMaterial .Add(new OtherMaterial());

foreach (Material m in ListMaterial )
{
   if (m is BendingMaterial)
   {
       string x = (m as BendingMaterial).Bendability;
   }
   if (m is OtherMaterial)
   {
       bool y = (m as OtherMaterial).IsOther;
   }
}
//more code
```

Comment: This is also possible but i have to recode my other methods, is there a way i can convert resultMaterial to a specific one? something like T resultMaterial = new BendingMaterial() ?

Comment: Well, if your intent is to treat the resultMaterial variable like it's a BendingMaterial, assuming you've already done a type check and you know that you won't get a runtime error trying to do that cast, you could do BendingMaterial b = (runtimeMaterial as BendingMaterial); and then access the properties and methods of b the BendingMaterial.  T resultMaterial = new BendingMaterial() will compile, but may not do what you're after in every case.  It gets you away from generics, but you might also consider Material m = new BendingMaterial(); since you know that you have a list of Materials.

Comment: Managed to fix it i changed the return to type to Material instead of T, `Material m = new BendingMaterial();` did the trick, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
BendingMaterial m = (BendingMaterial)(object)mrep.SearchMaterial(inpm);
```

and

```
List<BendingMaterial> b = ListMaterial.OfType<BendingMaterial>().ToList();
```